# Simple programming in C; trouble with pointers and memory allocation

Tags: c, pointers, memory-leaks

I am trying to solve a C problem demonstrating some of the language's basic capabilities, such as function formation, pointers, memory allocation and matrix manipulation. However, whenever I run it, I get an error, which I will tell in detail later on.

The program is formulated like this:

Write a program in the C programming language that simulates working with a large sparse matrix with positive integer numbers.

1. The maximum number of rows and columns of the matrix is 4000000000 (4 * 109), and all Matrix fields initially have a value of 0.
2. Matrix data is stored within another Matrix which has 3 columns and an arbitrary number of rows.
3. Information about each field of a large matrix that is different from zero is stored within one row of a smaller matrix, in the following order: the number of rows, the number of columns and the value of a given field in a large matrix.
4. Example: Matrix [[0, 0, 7], [0, 0, 0], [4, 0, 0]] is preserved as follows [[0, 2, 7], [2, 0, 4]].
5. Program from the standard input reads the data on the number of rows and columns of a large matrix, and then reads from the standard input and performs operations on The Matrix.
6. Operations are given by a character (operator) indicating a type of operation, which may be followed by additional parameters necessary to perform the data manipulation.

It is possible to perform the following operations:

- d row col br - in the field [row] [col] writes the value of br
- i row col - prints the value that is in the [row][col] field
- z row - prints the sum of the Matrix elements found in the given row
- n - specifies the number of Matrix elements that have a non-zero value
- q - completes the program.

If, when performing one of the operations, the number of a row or column that is out of range is given, the matrix displays the error value. Make sure that only data stored in the memory is of Matrix elements that are not equal to zero.

The Program has to do the following:

1. loads the number of types and the number of columns of the large row Matrix.
2. invokes a function that reads the operation from the standard input and invokes the corresponding function that performs the operation.
3. executes Step 2 until a program termination operation is entered

It sounds quite lengthy, but is actually not supposed to be too difficult at all. Here is how I tried to code this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 4000000000
#define TEST_GRESKE(red, kol, m, n) \
if ((red < 0 || red > m) || (kol < 0 || kol > n)){ \
            printf("GRESKA"); \
            exit(-1); \
        }

int **upisi_vrednost(int **a, int red, int kol, int vr, int m, int n){
        TEST_GRESKE(red, kol, m, n);
        a[red][kol] = vr;
        return a;
        }

void ispisi_vrednost(int **a, int red, int kol, int m, int n){
        TEST_GRESKE(red, kol, m, n);
        printf(a[red][kol]);
    }

int ispisi_zbir(int **a, int red, int m, int n){
        if (red < 0 || red > m){
            printf("GRESKA");
        }
        int suma = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            suma += a[red][j];
        }
        printf(suma);
        return suma;
}

int main(){
    int **a, **b, m, n, i, j, suma;

    scanf("%d %d", &m, &n);

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++){
        a[i] = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++){
            a[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    while(1){
        char operator;
        scanf("%s", &operator);

        if (operator == 'q'){
            for (i = 0; i < m; i++){
                for (j = 0; j < n; j++){
                    free(a[i][j]);
                }
            }
            break;
        }

        int red, kol, br;

        if (operator == 'd'){
            scanf("%d %d %d", &red, &kol, &br);
            a = upisi_vrednost(a, red, kol, br, m, n);

        }

        if (operator == 'i'){
            scanf("%d %d", &red, &kol);
            ispisi_vrednost(a, red, kol, m, n);
        }

        if (operator == 'z'){
            scanf("%d", &red);
            ispisi_zbir(a, red, m, n);
            }

        if (operator == 'n'){
            br = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < m; i++){
                for (j = 0; j < n; j++){
                    if (a[i][j] != 0){
                        br++;
                    }
                }
            }
            printf(br);
        }
    }
}
```

However, I do not get the right outputs at all. I get a bus error or segmentation fault, depending on the specific attempt to run the program, and those errors are related to trying to access memory that isn't there.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Did run your code in a **debugger** to see where that error occurs, then run it again with a breakpoint near that failure so you can step carefully ahead and watch what happens leading up to that point?

Comment: `scanf("%s", &operator);` is for reading a string into an array of characters, not for reading into a single character. Use `" %c"` for that and note the space before `%` is important.

Comment: You never allocated any space for `a`.  Instead, you immediately attempt to store into it, via `a[i] = malloc(...)`.  This is an undefined pointer access.  You're trying to store to `*(a+i)`, even though `a` is undefined.  You need to allocate space for `a`.

Comment: @TomKarzes I'm sorry, I'm new to C. I thought ''allocating space for a variable'' is precisely what malloc and calloc were doing. So, how do I perform the thing you are talking about syntactically? Thank you for your response.

Comment: @WilliamFrog8 To allocate space for `a`, you need `a = malloc(m * sizeof(int *))`.  There are two levels of allocation, one for `a`, and one for each element of `a`.  It might help you to put this aside and instead try working out a one-dimensional case.  Once you understand that, then you can move on to arrays of pointers.

Comment: I think ... Since you're familiar with python, AFAIK [and I could be wrong], python only has 1D arrays. 2D arrays are formed by a 1D array of references/pointers to 1D arrays (similar to perl). C has _true_ 2D arrays. But, this problem wants you to implement a _sparse_ matrix using a 1D array of pointers (of dimension 3) to 1D arrays (of struct/descriptors?) where each such 2nd level array is of variable length. So, the impl is similar to python, if that helps.

Comment: I think you are not supposed to alloc a m*n matrix in this homework: you're supposed to write a code that works with only the Matrix that has 3 columns.

Comment: I concur with Joël, you can't allocate that matrix in memory, it is specified to be allowed to be too big.

Comment: But I don't understand how I'm supposed to dynamically append the other matrix I'm supposed to create...

Comment: Maybe having a look at the realloc function may gives you some ideas.

Comment: If I answered your original question please accept the answer.  If you have a different question open a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you address the compiler warnings and issues with allocations and pointers:

1. Use format strings with `printf()`.
2. `main()`: Allocate allocate space for `a`.
3. Minimize lifetime/scope of variables.
4. `main()`: You skip initial space read a a character with the format string " %c" (not "%s").
5. Check the return value from `scanf()` otherwise you may be operating on uninitialized data.
6. Check the return value from `malloc()` otherwise you segfault if it fails.
7. `TEST_GRESKE` upper bounds are wrong should be `red >= m` and `kol >= n`.  If you used an unsigned type (`unsigned` or `size_t`) then you wouldn't need the check for negative indices).
8. (Not fixed) The tests on `operator` are mutually exclusive so either use `if-else if` or use a `switch`.  If you use a `switch` then you need a `goto` or a loop variable to exit the outer loop.  For example instead of `while(1) { ... }` use `do { ... } while(operator != 'q');`

I think it's in your best interest that I don't do your assignment for you.

The point of the assignment is simulate a sparse index but you operate on a regular non-sparse matrix.  Point 2 & 4 are strong hints as to how you implement the sparse matrix.

The first numbered requirement "The maximum number of rows and columns of the matrix is 4000000000 (4 * 109), and all Matrix fields initially have a value of 0." isn't fully addressed.  You are not using MAX_SIZE anywhere, also note, on my system 4e9 > INT_MAX so you need to use a different data type for your matrix indices.  I suggest you pick a suitable type from stdint.h instead of a platform dependent type.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 4000000000
#define TEST_GRESKE(red, kol, m, n) \
    if ((red < 0 || red >= m) || (kol < 0 || kol >= n)){ \
        printf("GRESKA"); \
        exit(-1); \
    }

int **upisi_vrednost(int **a, int red, int kol, int vr, int m, int n) {
    TEST_GRESKE(red, kol, m, n);
    a[red][kol] = vr;
    return a;
}

void ispisi_vrednost(int **a, int red, int kol, int m, int n){
    TEST_GRESKE(red, kol, m, n);
    printf("%d", a[red][kol]);
}

int ispisi_zbir(int **a, int red, int m, int n){
    if (red < 0 || red > m) {
        printf("GRESKA");
    }
    int suma = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
        suma += a[red][j];
    }
    printf("%d", suma);
    return suma;
}

int main(){
    int m, n;
    if(scanf("%d %d", &m, &n) != 2) {
        printf("scanf failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int **a;
    a = malloc(sizeof *a * m);
    if(!a) {
        printf("malloc failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++){
        a[i] = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
        if(!a[i]) {
            printf("malloc failed\n");
            return 1;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            a[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    while(1) {
        char operator;
        if(scanf(" %c", &operator) != 1) {
            printf("scanf failed\n");
            return 1;
        }
        if (operator == 'q') {
            for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
                free(a[i]);
            free(a);
            break;
        }

        int red, kol, br;
        if (operator == 'd'){
            if(scanf("%d %d %d", &red, &kol, &br) != 3) {
                printf("scanf failed\n");
                return 1;
            }
            a = upisi_vrednost(a, red, kol, br, m, n);

        }

        if (operator == 'i'){
            if(scanf("%d %d", &red, &kol) != 2) {
                printf("scanf failed\n");
                return 1;
            }
            ispisi_vrednost(a, red, kol, m, n);
        }

        if (operator == 'z'){
            if(scanf("%d", &red) != 1) {
                printf("scanf failed\n");
                return 1;
            }
            ispisi_zbir(a, red, m, n);
        }

        if (operator == 'n'){
            br = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < m; i++){
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
                    if (a[i][j] != 0){
                        br++;
                    }
                }
            }
            printf("%d", br);
        }
    }
}
```

example session:

```
1 2
d
0 0 42
d
0 1 43
n
2i
0 0
42i
0 1
43z
0
85q
```

Consider adding a bit more of output so it's easier to see what is going on.

Comment: What about the 3 columns Matrix?

Comment: @JoëlHecht I didn't read the assignment just fixed issue that op asked about (pointers and memory allocation).

Answer (score 1):

Allan identified most of your issues, but I want to expand on one thing.

You need to allocate space for `a` to point to before allocating space for each `a[i]`.  `a` is not an array - it's just a pointer.  You need to allocate an array of `int *` and assign a pointer to its first element to `a`.  *Then* you can allocate memory for each `a[i]`:

```
a = malloc( sizeof *a * m ); // sizeof *a == sizeof (int *)

for ( size_t i = 0; i < m; i++ )
  a[i] = malloc( sizeof *a[i] * n ); // sizeof *a[i] == sizeof (int)
```

When you're done, you'll have something that looks like this:

```
   int **       int *             int
   +---+        +---+             +---+
a: |   | -----> |   | a[0] -----> |   | a[0][0]
   +---+        +---+             +---+
                |   | a[1] --+    |   | a[0][1]
                +---+        |    +---+
                 ...         |     ...
                             |
                             |    +---+ 
                             +--> |   | a[1][0]
                                  +---+
                                  |   | a[1][1]
                                  +---+
```

The local variable `a` points to the first element of an array of `int *`, each of which points to the first element of an array of `int`.  You were skipping that first step, so `a` wasn't pointing to anything in particular, which means each `a[i]` operation was attempting to dereference an invalid pointer.